# Use Powered by Google without importing full Play Services Library?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm need to display a "Powered by Google" as per their terms and conditions. However, for that I have to import the entire Google Play Library, i.e. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

Any idea how I can get around this without importing the entire library? My app size is around 20 MB because of this while it could easily be only 1 or 2 MB without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a bit of Googling revealed this link from where I can download the necessary logos

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies#logo_requirements